# Timeout expired -> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, connection-pooling

I'm expecting very frustrating issue and can't find a reason.

There is an app, hosted on Azure, which uses MySQL db. I'm using MySQL.Data nuget from Oracle (6.10.5).
Very often I get Timeout expired error with Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts (dozen per 24 hours).

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

Stack Trace:

```
    [MySqlException (0x80004005): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) +177
   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) +37
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +55

[MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +151
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() +50
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) +225
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() +15
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() +288
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() +93
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() +65
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +629
   SalesManager.Models.ConnectionClass.QueryExec() in C:\Users\Gabinet\Source\Repos\SalesManager\SalesManager\SalesManager\Models\Data\ConnectionClass.cs:39
   SalesManager.Models.ProductDownload.GetStorageQuantity(Int32 id) in C:\Users\Gabinet\Source\Repos\SalesManager\SalesManager\SalesManager\Models\ProductDownload.cs:58
   SalesManager.Controllers.SalesController.Index(String sortOrder, String df, String dt) in C:\Users\Gabinet\Source\Repos\SalesManager\SalesManager\SalesManager\Controllers\SalesController.cs:41
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +194
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +169
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +33
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +11
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +577
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +157
```

Azure App Insights gives only timeout:

```
Event code: 3005

Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.

Event time: 22/12/2017 14:40:56

Event time (UTC): 22/12/2017 14:40:56

Event ID: 503190c80af54cdb87140fe1f808de22

Event sequence: 16

Event occurrence: 5

Event detail code: 0



Application information:

    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/41351921/ROOT-1-131584264107173868

    Trust level: Full

    Application Virtual Path: /

    Application Path: D:\home\site\wwwroot\

    Machine name: RD00155D58C141



Process information:

    Process ID: 10784

    Process name: w3wp.exe

    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\xxxx



Exception information:

    Exception type: MySqlException

    Exception message: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()





Request information:

    Request URL: http://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/

    Request path: /

    User host address: xx.xxx.xxx.xx

    User: xxxxx

    Is authenticated: True

    Authentication Type: ApplicationCookie

    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\xxxx



Thread information:

    Thread ID: 35

    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\xxxx

    Is impersonating: False

    Stack trace:    at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
```

I can't trigger this error on my local machine.
I can ping my MySql db from Azure.
Credentials are ok - it works just fine on my local machine.

Connection class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace SalesManager.Models
{
    public class ConnectionClass : IDisposable
    {
        private MySqlConnection _con;
        private MySqlCommand _cmd;
        private MySqlDataAdapter _da;
        private DataTable _dt;

        private string _constr =
            "Server=mysqldb.com; Database=databaseName; Uid=database_user; Pwd=database_pass; Default Command Timeout=300000; ";

        public ConnectionClass()
        {
            _con = new MySqlConnection(_constr);
        }

        public void MySqlQuery(string sqlquery)
        {
            _cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlquery, _con);
        }

        public void MySqlQueryWithParam(string sqlquery, string paramName, string paramValue)
        {
            _cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlquery, _con);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, paramValue);
        }

        public DataTable QueryExec()
        {
            _con.Open();
            _da = new MySqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
            _dt = new DataTable();
            _da.Fill(_dt);
            _con.Dispose();
            return _dt;
        }

        public void NonQueryExec()
        {
            _con.Open();
            _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _con.Dispose();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _con.Close();
            _con.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Method that fails:

```
public static int GetStorageQuantity(int id)
{
    if (id != 9999)
    {
        connection = new ConnectionClass();
        string sql = "select quantity from ps_stock_available where id_product = @pId";
            connection.MySqlQueryWithParam(sql, "@pId", id.ToString());
            var dr = connection.QueryExec().Rows[0];
            var quantity = Convert.ToInt32(dr["quantity"].ToString());
            return quantity;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My guess would be that I'm missing something related to connection pool which I'm not familiar with.

Any idea what could be the reason? What else can be checked?

Your help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In cases such as these, it is always worth starting by using your disposable stuff well...

```
using (var connection = new ConnectionClass()) {
    //...
}
```

It is possible that you are making too many connections, that are only being closed when GC calls the dispose method. The using statement will close connections earlier and this may solve the issue.

It is also possible the issue is caused by other factors, but I have found closing connections deliberately to be the solution to many similar problems.

Comment: I was using "using" in the previous iteration of ConnectionClass and expected the same issue. But will try again. Thanks

Comment: Exactly same error. I can't understand why it works on the local machine and fails on Azure.

Comment: Does it ever work on Azure, i.e. is it intermittent - or every time?

Comment: It's periodic. Sometimes it works on Azure and sometimes I get timeouts. In the same moment, it does work on my local machine and does not work on Azure.

Comment: Where is the MySQL database... on Azure or on your network / elsewhere? There could be a lot of different tin between you and the DB and Azure and the DB.

Comment: MySQL db is hosted on vipserv.org hosting provider. Not my network, not on Azure.

Comment: I really hate to say this, but it might be time to raise a support ticket as you'll need more information from the hosting provider. I feel bad saying this a couple of days before Christmas though!

Comment: Fortunately, it's my private application - not business one! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161827/discussion-between-fenton-and-beribazoo).